# getRange - copyTo not seeing a range that seems like a real range

Tags: google-sheets-api

I've got getRange/copyTo working elsewhere in the same script, but it's not working here.

The exception is "Range not found" in this line:

```
spreadsheet.getRange(copy_from_range).copyTo(copy_to_range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

While I'm able to use these ranges in other commands:

```
spreadsheet.setActiveRange(copy_from_range); - this works fine
```

They don't seem to be recognized as ranges with the getRange/copyTo

I create the range with

```
var copy_to_range = sheet.getRange(top_row,copy_to_col,num_rows,8);
```

And it's curious: this only works if I refer to the sheet rather than the spreadsheet, which I get with

```
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
```

But, as I said, both copy_from_range and copy_to_range act normally: I can set the ActiveRange, using toast it comes back "Range".

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

- getRange wants an a1 notation as input
- copyTo wants a range object as input